# Shared ancestor between two views

Tags: ios, algorithm, uiview, uikit

What is the most efficient way to find the lowest common ancestor between two `UIView` instances?

Short of implementing [Lowest Common Ancestor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor), are there any `UIKit` APIs that can be leveraged to find it?

`NSView` has `ancestorSharedWithView:` so I suspect this might be added sooner than later to iOS.

I'm currently using this quick and dirty solution, which is inefficient if the given view isn't a sibling or direct ancestor.

```
- (UIView*)lyt_ancestorSharedWithView:(UIView*)aView
{
    if (aView == nil) return nil;
    if (self == aView) return self;
    if (self == aView.superview) return self;
    UIView *ancestor = [self.superview lyt_ancestorSharedWithView:aView];
    if (ancestor) return ancestor;
    return [self lyt_ancestorSharedWithView:aView.superview];
}
```

(for those implementing a similar method, the unit tests of the [Lyt](https://github.com/robotmedia/Lyt) project might be helpful)

Comment: Your only option is to walk the `superview` chain up to top and then find where to two diverge. I'm not aware of any API (other than `superview`) that will help.

Comment: I don't know about API, but I would not go all the up to the top; instead go up in an alternating manner, keeping a counter for each UIView that I find and increase that counter by 1 every time I visit it. The first UIView to have its counter set to 2 is the lowest common ancestor. You can map views to their counter with a hashmap for example. That's the simplest thing I can think of and wouldn't be hard to implement.

Answer (score 10):

It's not too hard, using -isDescendantOfView:.

```
- (UIView *)my_ancestorSharedWithView:(UIView *)aView
{
    UIView *testView = self;
    while (testView && ![aView isDescendantOfView:testView])
    {
        testView = [testView superview];
    }
    return testView;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 3:**

```
extension UIView {
    func findCommonSuperWith(_ view:UIView) -> UIView? {

        var a:UIView? = self
        var b:UIView? = view
        var superSet = Set<UIView>()
        while a != nil || b != nil {

            if let aSuper = a {
                if !superSet.contains(aSuper) { superSet.insert(aSuper) }
                else { return aSuper }
            }
            if let bSuper = b {
                if !superSet.contains(bSuper) { superSet.insert(bSuper) }
                else { return bSuper }
            }
            a = a?.superview
            b = b?.superview
        }
        return nil

    }
}
```

Comment: Setting aside the space complexity, which I think is O(a+b) (where a and b are the distance from the view to the root view for each of those.) I think this is the most efficient, time wise. Unless the LCA is the root view, this algorithm won't have to walk the entire path from neither a nor b to the root, it will find the LCA before that. Nice!

Answer (score 4):

A functional alternative:

**Swift (assuming the use of your favourite `OrderedSet`)**

```
extension UIView {

    func nearestCommonSuperviewWith(other: UIView) -> UIView {
        return self.viewHierarchy().intersect(other.self.viewHierarchy()).first
    }

    private func viewHierarchy() -> OrderedSet<UIView> {
        return Set(UIView.hierarchyFor(self, accumulator: []))
    }

    static private func hierarchyFor(view: UIView?, accumulator: [UIView]) -> [UIView] {
        guard let view = view else {
            return accumulator
        }
        return UIView.hierarchyFor(view.superview, accumulator: accumulator + [view])
    }
}
```

**Objective-C (implemented as a category on `UIView`, assuming the existence of a `firstObjectCommonWithArray` method)**

```
+ (NSArray *)hierarchyForView:(UIView *)view accumulator:(NSArray *)accumulator
{
    if (!view) {
        return accumulator;
    }
    else {
        return [self.class hierarchyForView:view.superview accumulator:[accumulator arrayByAddingObject:view]];
    }
}

- (NSArray *)viewHierarchy
{
    return [self.class hierarchyForView:self accumulator:@[]];
}

- (UIView *)nearestCommonSuperviewWithOtherView:(UIView *)otherView
{
    return [[self viewHierarchy] firstObjectCommonWithArray:[otherView viewHierarchy]];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a little shorter version, as a category on UIView:

```
- (UIView *)nr_commonSuperview:(UIView *)otherView
{
    NSMutableSet *views = [NSMutableSet set];
    UIView *view = self;

    do {
        if (view != nil) {
            if ([views member:view])
                return view;
            [views addObject:view];
            view = view.superview;
        }

        if (otherView != nil) {
            if ([views member:otherView])
                return otherView;
            [views addObject:otherView];
            otherView = otherView.superview;
        }
    } while (view || otherView);

    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation only check two view level in one iteration.

Here is mine:

```
+ (UIView *)commonSuperviewWith:(UIView *)view1 anotherView:(UIView *)view2 {
    NSParameterAssert(view1);
    NSParameterAssert(view2);
    if (view1 == view2) return view1.superview;

    // They are in diffrent window, so they wont have a common ancestor.
    if (view1.window != view2.window) return nil;

    // As we don’t know which view has a heigher level in view hierarchy,
    // We will add these view and their superview to an array.
    NSMutableArray *mergedViewHierarchy = [@[ view1, view2 ] mutableCopy];
    UIView *commonSuperview = nil;

    // Loop until all superviews are included in this array or find a view’s superview in this array.
    NSInteger checkIndex = 0;
    UIView *checkingView = nil;
    while (checkIndex < mergedViewHierarchy.count && !commonSuperview) {
        checkingView = mergedViewHierarchy[checkIndex++];

        UIView *superview = checkingView.superview;
        if ([mergedViewHierarchy containsObject:superview]) {
            commonSuperview = superview;
        }
        else if (checkingView.superview) {
            [mergedViewHierarchy addObject:superview];
        }
    }
    return commonSuperview;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mine is a bit longer and without using UIKit isDescendant function.

Method 1: With a method of finding LCA in trees. Time complexity:O(N), Space complexity: (1)

```
func findCommonSuper(_ view1:inout UIView, _ view2:inout UIView) -> UIView? {
    var level1 = findLevel(view1)
    var level2 = findLevel(view2)
    if level1 > level2 {
        var dif = level1-level2
        while dif > 0 {
            view1 = view1.superview!
            dif -= 1
        }
    } else if level1 < level2 {
        var dif = level2-level1
        while dif > 0 {
            view2 = view2.superview!
            dif -= 1
        }
    }
    while view1 != view2  {
        if view1.superview == nil || view2.superview == nil {
            return nil
        }
        view1 = view1.superview!
        view2 = view2.superview!
    }
    if view1 == view2 {
        return view1
    }
    return nil
}

func findLevel(_ view:UIView) -> Int {
    var level = 0
    var view = view
    while view.superview != nil {
        view = view.superview!
        level += 1
    }
    return level
}
```

Method 2: Inserting one view's ancestors to set and then iterating second ones ancestors. Time complexity: O(N), Space complexity: O(N)

```
func findCommonSuper2(_ view1:UIView, _ view2:UIView) -> UIView? {
    var set = Set<UIView>()
    var view = view1
    while true {
        set.insert(view)
        if view.superview != nil {
            view = view.superview!
        } else {
            break
        }
    }

    view = view2
    while true {
        if set.contains(view) {
            return view
        }
        if view.superview != nil {
            view = view.superview!
        } else {
            break
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 2.0:

```
    let view1: UIView!
    let view2: UIView!
    let sharedSuperView = view1.getSharedSuperview(withOtherView: view2)

/**
* A set of helpful methods to find shared superview for two given views
*
* @author Alexander Volkov
* @version 1.0
*/
extension UIView {

    /**
    Get nearest shared superview for given and otherView

    - parameter otherView: the other view
    */
    func getSharedSuperview(withOtherView otherView: UIView) {
        (self.getViewHierarchy() as NSArray).firstObjectCommonWithArray(otherView.getViewHierarchy())
    }

    /**
    Get array of views in given view hierarchy

    - parameter view:        the view whose hierarchy need to get
    - parameter accumulator: the array to accumulate views in

    - returns: the list of views from given up to the top most view
    */
    class func getHierarchyForView(view: UIView?, var accumulator: [UIView]) -> [UIView] {
        if let superview = view?.superview {
            accumulator.append(view!)
            return UIView.getHierarchyForView(superview, accumulator: accumulator)
        }
        return accumulator
    }

    /**
    Get array of views in the hierarchy of the current view

    - returns: the list of views from cuurent up to the top most view
    */
    func getViewHierarchy() -> [UIView] {
        return UIView.getHierarchyForView(self, accumulator: [])
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5 version of [Carl Lindberg's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38127313/2095408):

```
func nearestCommonSuperviewWith(other: UIView) -> UIView? {
    var nearestAncestor: UIView? = self

    while let testView = nearestAncestor, !other.isDescendant(of: testView) {
        nearestAncestor = testView.superview
    }

    return nearestAncestor
}
```